# How to properly add textarea to tabbedpane

Tags: java, jtextarea, jtabbedpane

I have an assignment to create a multitab editor something like Gedit .So I have used JTabbedPane and added JTextArea in its constructor . I am facing problem while using methods textarea.cut(); where textarea is textarea as if user creates new tab user must be able to implement cut,copy,paste. so I used tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent().But Now it says that component cannot be converted to jTextArea so I used typecasted it .The question is I am not getting the expected output i.e It is not  adding tabs properly My question is How to add these components to tabbed pane in a clean and efficient way. Any alternative methods of doing it are most welcome.

Here is snippets of my code.

```
         //components declared in class Editor which extends Jframe
        JTextArea textarea ;
        JScrollPane scrollpane ;
        JTabbedPane tabbedpane ;

        public Editor(){

    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    tabbedpane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedpane.addTab("File",textarea);
    add(tabbedpane);
    scrollpane = new JScrollPane(tabbedpane);
    getContentPane().add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //content in my constructor

   //also contains other components but are not shown here. 
   } //end constructor



        //add new Tabs
          newfile = new JMenuItem("New File");
           file.add(newfile);
           newfile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                   tabbedpane = new JTabbedPane();
                   tabbedpane.addTab("File",textarea);
                   add(tabbedpane);
                  scrollpane = new JScrollPane(tabbedpane);
                  getContentPane().add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }//end actionPerformed
           });//end method new 

           this.add(tabbedpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);



             //added cut as JMenuItem to Menu edit Which is then added toJMenuBar



                cut = new JMenuItem("Cut");
                edit.add(cut);
                cut.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ActionEvent){

            JTextArea txtarea = new JTextArea();
            txtarea = (JTextArea)tabbedpane.getSelectedComponent();
                txtarea.cut();

        }//end actionPerformed

    });//end Method cut
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab key (tab name) should differ, and your TabbedPane you should add only once.

```
//constructor
public Editor() {
    tabs = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP, JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    add(tabs, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

//class method
void addFile(String name) {
    tabs.addTab(name, new JScrollPane(new TextArea()));
}
```